# Git gets renames (a swap) of files wrong. How to merge them automatically?

Tags: git, file-rename

I have file which is is being edited on some branch, and in my branch I swap its name with some other file. Git will report merge conflict on both files and produces wrong `diff`.

Is it possible to avoid result like one below without undoing the renames before every time I merge?

```
$ git diff master
diff --git a/old.txt b/old.txt
index 7b4dc35..e73e0b4 100644
--- a/old.txt
+++ b/old.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,2 @@
-This is an old file.
-A Corrected Text again.
-More Text.
+This is a second file.
+Do not confuse with original.
diff --git a/old2.txt b/old2.txt
index e73e0b4..8f51c7b 100644
--- a/old2.txt
+++ b/old2.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,4 @@
-This is a second file.
-Do not confuse with original.
+This is an old file.
+A Corrected Text.
+More Text.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no", because of the rename detection algorithm git uses.

In general, when comparing one commit against another, diff does this:

- Find all files whose name appears in both commits: these files are modified (or of course unchanged).
- Find files whose name appears in the second commit but not in the first, and whose name appears in the first commit but not in the second: these are candidates for rename-detection.
- If given "find copy" options, find files whose name appears in the second commit but not the first; these are candidates for being "copied from" files that *do* exist in the first commit.

When you use `git diff` directly, you have a bunch of configuration items and flags that control the amount of detection applied, as it were: `diff.renameLimit`, `-M`, `-C`, and `--find-copies-harder` in particular.

When you use `git merge` with the default (recursive) strategy, git sets these to default values that usually work fairly well.  There are some (fewer) controls to adjust them: `merge.renameLimit` and `-X rename-threshold=...`.<sup>1</sup>  Git applies these to the two `git diff`s it runs internally in order to set up for the merge.

The problem, of course, is that the first bullet-point (files with same names are not considered as rename candidates, only sometimes as copy candidates) applies in all cases.  Git therefore will not see these as renames.

---

<sup>1</sup>Even these options are somewhat new: I remember when merge just hard-coded these.  Perhaps you can teach diff and merge to allow for rename detection in cases when file names exist in both commits.  (Both use the same underlying diff code inside git, with a data structure that controls the various options.)